# Laravel 1048 Column cannot be NULL on storing data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I'm trying to save a new contact I'm getting `1048 Column 'username' cannot be NULL` error. It's pretty obvious that cause of this error is empty value of `username`, however I'd like to make it work without setting a column to NULL or checking if `username` POST data is empty and then setting it's value to `''`.

I've seen numerous of examples, where column is not set to NULL and/or data is not set to `''` before saving to database.

Or maybe I'm wrong and I missed something ?

I hope someone could comment on that..

```
$contact = new Contact;
$contact->name      = Input::get('name'); 
$contact->username  = Input::get('username');
$nerd->save();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set default non-null values for the Input variable(s).

```php
$contact = new Contact;
$contact->name     = Input::get('name');
$contact->username = Input::get('username', '');
$contact->save();
```

Or, in more recent Laravel versions:

```php
$contact = new Contact;
$contact->name     = $request->input('name');
$contact->username = $request->input('username', '');
$contact->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use model events (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).

When a Contact is `creating` or `updating`, you can test if username is null, and change it to `''` before writing it to DB.

Comment: This is to an answer. In future, please be sure to provide code to show how to solve poster's question.

Answer (score 0):

This error may also occur if a field is not included in the model's `$fillable` property. For example, with this code:

```php
class User extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ["name", "email", "phone"];
}

$user = User::create([
    "name" => "Joe Bloggs",
    "email" => "joe@example.com",
    "address" => "14 Sutton Drive, Dublin 13",
    "phone" => "0866582753",
]);
```

The `address` value will not be passed to the database query, which may result in the 1048 error. (If the `address` column is declared nullable, no error will be thrown, but the column will also never be updated by any [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) methods.)

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. This value is not null in database and from front end it send a null value. The error is shown below

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'MoneyMethod' cannot be null".
```

My view page input tag:

```
{!! Form::select("MoneyMethod", $MoneymethodInfo, null,["class"=>"form-control MoneyMethod required","id"=>"MoneyMethod"]) !!},
```

notice the spelling of 'MoneyMethod' in my database table `$table->string('MoneyMethod', 100);` the spelling of money method is same as view page but in my controller

```
$riskfund->Moneymethod  = Input::get('Moneymethod');
```

look carefully the spelling of 'Moneymethod' differs from view page and database table column. After correcting the spelling, it is now getting the value.

So, please check the spelling of 'username' in form, controller, database table and also notice that the database field is nullable or not.