# Laravel: field already set to nullable: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'affiliate_link' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I have already read the following links, but it didn't solve my problem

[Laravel 5.4 Upgrade -- Integrity constraint violation - Column cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860634/laravel-5-4-upgrade-integrity-constraint-violation-column-cannot-be-null)

[Laravel 1048 Column cannot be NULL on storing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391744/laravel-1048-column-cannot-be-null-on-storing-data)

https://laravel.io/forum/04-20-2014-sqlstate23000-column-user-id-cannot-be-null

I am using laravel version 5.5.34

My problem is

This is validation in store method of the controller

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'content'=>'required',
        'affiliate_link' => 'nullable|string'
    ]);
```

As you can see I set the affiliate_link column name to be nullable and if it's available should be string.

But it throws the following error

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'affiliate_link' cannot be
>   null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your migration file. Are you allowing users to post empty data in your migration file?

Comment: I not using migration. I have directly created the table in phpmyadmin, I checked the null is not set, so I set it to null it works now, thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `affiliate_link` column is set to allow null. If not you may want to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **affiliate_link** column is set to allow null in your database the problem is just because of this try to set it and the error gone hope this will help you.